# Firefox Quantum - reduce multiple prompts for master password when accessing saved logins?

Tags: firefox, passwords

When viewing saved logins, earlier versions of Firefox would prompt once for the master password before showing the saved login passwords. This assumes the master password was entered correctly when prompted sometime after starting the browser.

With the Quantum/Lockwise changes, there are multiple, repeating prompts for the master password during the process of accessing the saved login data. 
Is this a bug, or is there a way to reduce the repeated requests?  Because the master password is important, mine is long and complex. Having to type it in several times in the space of a minute or two seems unnecessary and annoying.

Comment: [Firefox keeps asking me for master password | Firefox Help](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-keeps-asking-me-master-password)?

Comment: That is not the situation I'm referring to. It is expected that the master password is requested when starting Firefox. The problem is when accessing Saved Logins, it asks again for Master Password. That's OK, but then when I find a login and want to look at it it asks again. If I then want to copy it, it asks again. If I look at several different logins, each login, and each action on the login requires entering the master password over and over. That is a bit much, IHMO.